# Can I share a mine library to all applications?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, webforms, shared-libraries

I have a project (.NET 4, but I can have also .NET 4.5) that always use the same DLL I've made (it's mine Data Layer, more or less).

Each website it's an application.

I'd like to share this Library I have to each application, so if I do an update I'll update only a "folder", and I don't need to copy/paste this Library on each Bin folder on each web application.

Is it possible?

Such as, if I create my class `MyClass2013`, it will be available for each web application when I load Visual Studio:

```
MyClass2013 myClass = new MyClass2013()
```

without copy and paste the Bin's DLL (where I have the definition of this class/methods and so on) every time, for every application, keeping all of them updated if I do some edit.

Thinks to the Library `System` for example: is accessible for each project, I import nothing!

Comment: Install your dll to [Gac](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79.aspx) but still you need to refer it manually.

Comment: As Sriram said; for generic access to a single library, the GAC is the correct option. For your "its available in my project immediately" You could consider making a template for visual studio based on the project type you prefer and include a reference to the "gac'ed" library.

Comment: Why go to the bother of installing it on the GAC, whats wrong with maintaining your own library of DLLs external to the projects, and merely reference the relevent file in that one folder from any project? (basically the same as the GAC without having to install it into the GAC)

Comment: @PaulZahra: I don't understand, what do you mean? Example?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: if you write as answer, I'll accept it ;)

Answer (score 1):

With your mine datalayer project, if you have it compile to a folder say C:/DLL_Library

Say the DLL path is now C:/DLL_Library/mine.DLL

This DLL_Library folder could then house any DLLs, either ones used by multiple projects or one project (although some form of management would be helpful)

Say your projects are all in C:/Projects/

Within each project you simply reference the DLL at C:/DLL_Library/mine.DLL and copy this library of DLLs to any machine that compiles your other projects.

P.S. The [power tools Visual Studio addon](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) upgrades the referencing wizard in a nice way.

Comment: No! It "import it". So if external it changes, I need to re-import it in any projects! It is what i want to avoid...

Comment: A problem you'll find doing it the GAC way is with when u want to have multiple versions of an assembly in use.

Comment: I suppose there's an argument to be had here for using Web Services. Put it in the GAC on every workstation, use a DLL library and have it copied into each project at compile or use one centralised Web Service... hmm I know which I'd prefer.