# GAC on edit process?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, gac

Every time I do an edit on my Library Class, I compile it for get the updated DLL.
But for get the effective edit on the project which uses this Library, I have to do the command :

```
gacutil –I <assembly name >
```

and recycle the pool. Recycling the pool can be ok, but can I automate that process of `gacutil`?

Is there a way on VS or no solution? I need to do this every time?

Comment: The Deployment Framework for Biztalk menu has a one click button to deploy the output of a project to the gac - not sure of others but this is what I use.

Comment: yeah add the post build event on that project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep updating that project, In that case you can add build event to GAC automatically on that particular project using following post built event.Under Build Event in project properties just you can add the following post build event to GAC your modified dll.`Just copy and past following line with zero modification`

```
  "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe" /i "$(TargetPath)"
```

But make sure that `gacutil.exe` in that path.

Comment: Tried it in the Post-Building textarea inside VS: `"%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\gacutil.exe"  /i "C:\Users\marco\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ArchieDLLTesting\ArchieDLLTesting\ArchieDLLTesting\bin\Debug"` but it says there is an error, I don't understand where?

Comment: no need to change the $(TargetPath) variable keep it as same its varible from VS so just copy below code into event it should work {no need to replace with C:\Users\marco\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ArchieDLLTesting\ArchieDLLTesting\ArchieDLLTesting\bin\Debug}

Comment: Uhm ok! Now it returns error MSB3073, 9009! What's wrong now?